# xfce loading desktop only on guest session

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. Firefox crashed while I was normally browsing the web and the whole desktop froze. I logged into another shell (ctrl-alt-n) and shutdown the system. After reboot if I login with my usual account the desktop will fail to load, no icons, no menu bar, nothing. I tried deleting files in the

```
.cache/sessions
.config/xfce
```

folders, but it still not working.

Comment: Are you able to start desktop manager mannually using `xfdesktop` or `xfdesktop4`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using

```
xfwm4 --replace
```